# How to download picture via VBA directly in excel?

Tags: excel, vba, file, hyperlink

I have small code:

```
Dim DoOnce As Boolean
Public Function OnMouseOver(URL As String, TheCell As Range)
Reset
If Not DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = True
    With ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(URL)
        With .ShapeRange
            .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
            .Width = 300
            .Height = 300
        End With
        .Left = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Left
        .Top = Cells(TheCell.Row, TheCell.Column + 1).Top
        .Placement = 1
        .PrintObject = True
    End With
End If
End Function

Public Function Reset()
If DoOnce Then
    DoOnce = False
    ActiveSheet.Pictures.Delete
End If
End Function
```

which is loading picture when mouse is over cell with code:

```
=HYPERLINK(OnMouseOver("C:\Folder1\Folder2\"&C1&".jpg";B60);"PICTURE")
```

I can not understand why I cant use link for picture:

```
http://sadb.byethost7.com/SA0061218.jpg
```

Same time this is working:

```
http://www.tl.bialowieza.pl/sites/default/files/grafika/29d36911454aabfacf5ff4ba5fc4.jpeg
```

Comment: can you access to this into your navigator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After few tests I manage to load pictures from FTP. Look like that this is no issue with code but with server. Some servers allow loading pictures only via web browser. In my case I used free FTP [www.5v.pl](http://www.5v.pl) and it is OK now. Just long calculation during first excel opening.